# Selecting multiple conditionals in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I've just started using jq json parser, is there anyway to choose multiple `select`?
I have this:

```
cat file | jq -r '.Instances[] | {ip: .PrivateIpAddress, name: .Tags[]}
                               | select(.name.Key == "Name")'
```

And I need to also include the `.name.Key == "Type"`

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "Instances": [
    {
      "PrivateIpAddress": "1.1.1.1",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "Daily",
          "Key": "Backup"
        },
        {
          "Value": "System",
          "Key": "Name"
        },
        {
          "Value": "YES",
          "Key": "Is_in_Domain"
        },
        {
          "Value": "PROD",
          "Key": "Type"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the current output:

```
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "name": "System"
}
{
  "ip": "2.2.2.2",
  "name": "host"
}
{
  "ip": "3.3.3.3",
  "name": "slog"
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "name": "System",
  "type": "PROD"
}
{
  "ip": "2.2.2.2",
  "name": "host",
  "type": "PROD"
}
{
  "ip": "3.3.3.3",
  "name": "slog",
  "type": "PROD"
}
```

What is the right way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "right" way to do it, but there are approaches to take that can make things easier for you.

The tags are already in a format that makes converting to objects simple (they're object entries).  Convert the tags to an object for easy access to the properties.

```
$ jq '.Instances[]
    | .Tags |= from_entries
    | {
        ip:   .PrivateIpAddress,
        name: .Tags.Name,
        type: .Tags.Type
      }' file
```

Comment: Thanks. This query works on jq play but not on jq on my ubuntu machine. I get: `jq: error: Cannot use null as object key
{
  "type": null,
  "name": null,
  "ip": null
}` @Jeff Mercado

Comment: Do all tags in your data have `key` values? The error seems to indicate that some doesn't.

Comment: No, I think not all. Is there a way to avoid the error? @Jeff Mercado

Comment: Not sure, as I don't know what the cause of the error is. The example data you provided doesn't give that error. You should show us exactly what the data is and how you are invoking jq.

Comment: It's a very long json. There are some objects with `"Type": ""` (type null),
I tried `type: .Tags.Type // "nothing"` that didn't work

Comment: And not every object has `"Type"` @Jeff Mercado