# How to get a flat output based on conditional jq query?

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "InstanceA",
    "tags": [
      {
        "key": "environment",
        "value": "production"
      },
      {
        "key": "group",
        "value": "group1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "InstanceB",
    "tags": [
      {
        "key": "group",
        "value": "group2"
      },
      {
        "key": "environment",
        "value": "staging"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get a flat output of `value` based on the condition `key == 'environment'`. I already tried [`select(boolean_expression)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ConditionalsandComparisons), but I cannot get the desired output, like:

```
"InstanceA, production"
"InstanceB, staging"
```

Does `jq` support this kind of output? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting multiple conditionals in JQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614513/selecting-multiple-conditionals-in-jq)

Comment: You've noticed that key/value pairs are the same data structure used for `from_entries`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq '.[] | .name + ", " + (.tags[] | select(.key == "environment").value)' f.json
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

For example:

```
$ jq '.[] | "\(.name), \(.tags | from_entries | .environment)"' input.json
```

Output:

```
"InstanceA, production"
"InstanceB, staging"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using **join**

```
  .[]
| [.name, (.tags[] | if .key == "environment" then .value else empty end)]
| join(", ")
```